# ICP transformation matrix translation and rotation

Tags: c++, math, matrix, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a vehicle with a nice IMU and sonar. I am doing fine registrations of the sonar point clouds with the point cloud library linear ICP. I want to compare the results of the ICP transformation with the IMU data, but I don't understand how to extract the translation from the final homogeneous 4x4 transformation matrix.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956151/icp-transformation-matrix-interpretation) and [other sources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati) I've found all say that the translation is simply the 4th column in the form .

The problem I am having is that the values I am getting for translation are not possible, it seems like the larger the rotation component the more absurd the values get which leads to believe that I can not simply extract the last column. The roll, pitch, and yaw values are within reason and make sense but there is no way there is an offset of more than about 1 meter in any direction. The matrix does perform as expected when applied, so i know the matrix is correct I just don't understand how to interpret or extract the x,y,z linear translation.

Measuring the distance between the centroid of the original cloud and the final cloud gives much more reasonable results, but I don't know if this is an acceptable method. it seems kind of hacky.

Code:

```
myCloud::Ptr      target, source, output;  // PCL clouds
myPoint           cInit, cRough, cFinal;   // centroid points
Eigen::Matrix4f   estimation, icpResult, finalTransform;   // transforms

// load vectors of sonar data into point clouds
target = pointVector_to_pointCloud(verbose, tgtPoints);
source = pointVector_to_pointCloud(verbose, srcPoints);

pcl::computeCentroid(*source, cInit);

// x, y, z offsets come from a previous rough alignment
Eigen::Affine3f fromIMU(Eigen::Translation3f(x, y, z));
estimation = fromIMU.matrix();
pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud, *cloud, estimation);

pcl::computeCentroid(*source, cRough);

// create new empty cloud in the output pointer, set up ICP
output.reset(new myCloud);
icp.setInputSource(source);
icp.setInputTarget(target);

/**** Set ICP parameters, omitted ****/

icp.align(*output);
icpResult = icp.getFinalTransformation();
finalTransform = estimation * icpResult;

pcl::computeCentroid(*source, cFinal);

// Output Results
Eigen::Affine3f roughT(estimation);
Eigen::Affine3f fineT(icpResult);
float tx, ty, tz, rx, ry, rz;
pcl::getTranslationAndEulerAngles(roughT, tx, ty, tz, rx, ry, rz);
std::cerr << "********* ICP RESULTS **********\n";
std::cerr << "Rough Transform Matrix:\n" << transform << endl;
std::cerr << "Translation (x, y, z)       : " << tx << ", " << ty << ", " << tz << endl;
std::cerr << "Rotation (roll, pitch, yaw) : " << rx << ", " << ry << ", " << rz << endl;

pcl::getTranslationAndEulerAngles(fineT, tx, ty, tz, rx, ry, rz);
std::cerr << "\nFine Transform Matrix:\n" << icpResult << endl;
std::cerr << "Translation (x, y, z)       : " << tx << ", " << ty << ", " << tz << endl;
std::cerr << "Rotation (roll, pitch, yaw) : " << rx << ", " << ry << ", " << rz << endl << endl;

std::cerr << "\nFinal Transformation Matrix:\n" << finalTransform << endl;

std::cerr << "\n\tCentroid after Rough Alignment: " << cRough << " ... Distance From Start: " << pcl::geometry::distance(cInit, cRough) << endl;
std::cerr << "\tCentroid after ICP: " << cFinal << " ... Distance From Start: " << pcl::geometry::distance(cInit, cFinal) << endl;
```

which outputs (for one example dataset):

```
********* INSIDE ICP TRANSFORM STATS **********
Rough Transform Matrix:
        1         0         0  0.612095
        0         1         0 -0.211855
        0         0         1         0
        0         0         0         1
Translation (x, y, z)       : 0.612095, -0.211855, 0
Rotation (roll, pitch, yaw) : 0, -0, 0

Fine Transform Matrix:
   0.999992 -0.00257317  0.00361636     2.92558
 0.00256172    0.999995  0.00328003     2.66182
-0.00362478 -0.00327113    0.999988   0.0578782
          0           0           0           1
Translation (x, y, z)       : 2.92558, 2.66182, 0.0578782
Rotation (roll, pitch, yaw) : -0.00327116, 0.00362479, 0.00256174

Final Transformation Matrix: 
   0.999992 -0.00257317  0.00361636     3.53767
 0.00256172    0.999995  0.00328003     2.44996
-0.00362478 -0.00327113    0.999988   0.0578782
          0           0           0           1

Centroid after Rough Alignment: (8.8218,9.12704,-807.301 - 0,126,255) ... Distance From Start: 0.647709
Centroid after ICP: (8.8068,9.1658,-807.3 - 0,126,255) ... Distance From Start: 0.621667
```

Comment: Acceptable for what? Aren't you making the rules? The translation will depend on where the origin of the point cloud is. If it is far outside, the rotational part will already move the point cloud quite a bit. Then, the translation will just add to this movement. Using the centroids sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was related to the origin of the data. Bathymetry data is expressed as a positive number, the meters of sea water above a point. But the vehicle collecting the data is flying 10-30 meters above the sea floor.

To properly transform the data:

- Transform into the vehicle reference frame
- Perform ICP and obtain matrices
- Transform data back into Bathymetry frame if needed

This may require additional vehicle data to know the how to transform into vehicle frame, for example sensor locations and offsets on the vehicle itself.

Transformed into the vehicle reference frame,